# Is google app engine's ndb safe to use?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it pretty stable or am I going to risk having to rewrite code if I use it because it might change in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is stable and fully supported.

snippet from the [1.6.4 sdk release](http://googleappengine.blogspot.be/2012/03/app-engine-164-released.html)

```
- NDB for Python - The NDB API has graduated from experimental and is now a fully
  supported feature. This next-generation datastore API improves data modeling 
  and querying and has been built from the ground up to support an asynchronous
  computing model.
```